# using named ranges in a sumif formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, named-ranges

I have named ranges. They are columns on another tab within the workbook.  I'm using a sumif formula to find value based on multiple criteria.  The formula is =sumifs(H4,array1,b4,array2,c4). H4 is a cell where I'm using a validation list to select a named range to be the sum_range. My problem is this... if I type the actual name of the range in my formula, it works. But if I use the cell reference H4 which contains text of my named range, I get #VALUE!
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use INDIRECT():

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT(H4),array1,B4,array2,C4)
```

[image]

Comment: Be aware that INDIRECT() is a volatile function, meaning that it will recalculate every time any cell changes. This turns into a huge headache as the size of your sheet increases. To work around, you might name a second range to point to H4 and reference that.